# How to find whether a text contains zero?

Tags: python

I want to check in a piece of text whether that text contains "0" or not.

I cannot use `string.__contains(" 0")` as this is bad coding, or if I can use this, I do not have enough points to back to my senior, that this is the only way. Or if you can let me know some points?

The other way we found out is to extract from each row, and extract the number from it, convert it into integer and then check if the value is greater than 0. But this is little time consuming.

The string could contain a number like 2560 which should be ignored in this search.

Please tell me some alternative. I don't want that integer conversion.

For example:

```
abc : 1234
def : 1230  >>> This kind of text should return False

abc : 1234
def : 0  >>>> This kind of text should return True, as it contains 0.
```

Comment: The answers so far tell you how to say if there's a 0 somewhere in the string but, given that you say "2560" would be ignored, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes Ricardo.. This is exactly what I want. Is it possible using string search methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, I thought you could just use `in`:

```
if "0" in myString:
  print "%s contains 0" % myString
```

However, this doesn't seem to be what you want to do, when re-reading your question. This will detect the `0` in a row such as:

```
abc: 200
```

Which I guess you don't want to do. You need to use something a bit more sophisticated. I would probably go with some simple manual code, rather than using regular expressions as suggested in a different answer. Here's how:

```
def is_row_zero(row):
  parts = row.split(":")
  value = parts[1].strip()
  if value == "0":
    print "%s is 0, not allowed" % parts[0]
    return True
  return False
```

It's possible the regular expression approach is faster, so that might be worth investigating depending on your workload and performance goals.

Comment: Yes, I too have only this option left... because I don't think there is any other option available.;

Comment: can we use strip function to provide a regular expression in it...  if we want to strip the part of the row starting with some letters, and we want to strip that

Comment: No, don't go the regexp way. Evaluating regular expressions is usually slow when looking for very simple cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions to find a pattern:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\W(0)\W', 'alsdkjf 0 asdkfs0asdf   0   ')
['0', '0']
```

Where `\W(0)\W` matches zero surrounded by non-alphanumeric characters ('\W').

Your example:

```
>>> re.findall('\W(0)\W', 'abc : 1234 def : 1230 ')
[]
>>> re.findall('\W(0)\W', 'abc : 1234 def : 0 ')
['0']
```

Comment: This is what I said in my question above I thought of doing the same. But isn't there any other technique that is available..

Comment: The 'in' operator is much more appropriate for searching for a single character in a character string.

Comment: This is the way to go. Unlike other solutions, it'll match "0" delineated by non-space word boundaries like punctuation. The OP's question makes it clear they don't want to accept strings where the '0' character occurs inside a larger number.

Comment: Okay, but it should be \b, not \W.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to find this in Python...

```
if " 0 " in [string variable]:
    do something...
```

is one option, You could turn the " 0 " into a variable to make it more generic.

Regular expressions might be preferable, perhaps. But is overkill really.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, the input is a text file like:

```
label : value
label : value
...
```

I suggest you read the file line by line and use either regular expressions:

```
for line in open("filename.txt"):
    if re.match(r"\S+ : 0$", line):
        print "The row's value is zero"
```

Or use `.endswith`:

```
for line in open("filename.txt"):
    if line.endswith(" 0"):
         print "The row's value is zero"
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is just "0", then:

```
string == '0'
```

If there *may* be whitespace around:

```
string.strip() == '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't exactly clear, did you want a zero only if it's not part of a number?
You could check all 0's in the string, and see if its adjacent characters are digits.

something such as:

```
def has_zero(s):
    if "0" not in s:
        return False
    if s=="0":
        return True
    if s[0]=="0" and not s[1].isdigit():
        return True
    if s[-1]=="0" and not s[-2].isdigit():
        return True
    return any(s[i]=="0" and not (s[i-1].isdigit() or s[i+1].isdigit()) for i in range(1,len(s)-1))

print has_zero("hell0 w0rld")
#True
print has_zero("my number is 2560")
#False
print has_zero("try put a zer0 in here with number 100")
#True
print has_zero("0")
print has_zero("10")
print has_zero("01")
print has_zero("a0")
print has_zero("0a")
print has_zero("00")
```